# Is there an R function for evaluating the pdf for an ARIMA model given data and a parameter set?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, arima, log-likelihood

I'm unfamiliar with R, but I've been able to write code that estimates parameters for an ARIMA model of whatever order to some data I have in a file. It looks like this:

```
data <- read.table("ARMA22-series.csv", sep=" ", header=FALSE, dec=".")
data <- as.ts(data)
arima_results <- arima0(data, order=c(2, 0, 2), include.mean=FALSE)
```

However, I'm interested in evaluating the likelihood function for a certain set of parameter values, rather than just finding the parameters that maximise the likelihood for a given dataset. Is there a function that allows you to just evaluate the probability density of data, given values for the ARIMA parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about statistical methods and probabilities, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. If any of your variables are continuous then probability of observing any single value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using `arima0`, which is labelled as a preliminary version, and was replaced by `arima`.

`arima` fits a *specific* (S)ARIMA model to your data, with parameters specified through the function arguments `order` and `seasonal`. `forecast::auto.arima` tries to determine the optimal (S)ARIMA model conditional on the data.

The `arima` output object includes the log-likelihood; for example, consider the `USAccDeaths` sample data, we can fit the two SARIMA models: SARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1) and SARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0).

```
fit1 <- arima(USAccDeaths, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1)))
fit2 <- arima(USAccDeaths, order = c(0, 1, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0)))
```

The `arima` output object is a `list`, and the log-likelihood is stored in element `loglik`:

```
fit1$loglik
#[1] -425.44
fit2$loglik
#[1] -435.8443
```